# Why is my Tkinter button command ignoring the arguments I'm sending into a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, spyder

I'm attempting to create a GUI for astrophotography, and am trying to add a function that would allow choosing a specific directory for files. I'm using a button with a command, and am trying to run the function (that has an argument) using the lambda function. However, trying to run it I was given a TypeError: uploadFlats() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'.

```
class Astrophotography:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWin = tk.Tk()
        self.mainWin.title("Automatic Image Editor")
        self.firstFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainWin, width = 600, height = 200)
        self.secondFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainWin)
        self.thirdFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainWin)
        
    
        # First Frame
        
        self.description = tk.Label(self.firstFrame, text = "Please select a save directory and also directories\
 for flats, biases, and darks to create masters of each")
 
 
        self.flatsLabel = tk.Label(self.firstFrame, text = "Please enter flats directory: ")
        self.flatsText = tk.StringVar(value = "")
        self.flatsEntry = tk.Entry(self.firstFrame, width = 50, textvariable = self.flatsText)
        self.browseflats = tk.Button(self.firstFrame, text = "Browse",
                                     command = lambda: self.uploadFlats(self.flatsText))
        
        self.flatsLabel = tk.Label(self.firstFrame, text = "Please enter flats directory: ")
        self.flatsText = tk.StringVar()
        self.flatsEntry = tk.Entry(self.firstFrame, width = 50, textvariable = self.flatsText)
        self.browseflats = tk.Button(self.firstFrame, text = "Browse", command = self.uploadFlats)
        
        self.darksLabel = tk.Label(self.firstFrame, text = "Please enter darks directory: ")
        self.darksText = tk.StringVar()
        self.darksEntry = tk.Entry(self.firstFrame, width = 50, textvariable = self.darksText)
        self.browsedarks = tk.Button(self.firstFrame, text = "Browse", command = self.uploadDarks)
        
        self.biasLabel = tk.Label(self.firstFrame, text = "Please enter bias directory: ")
        self.biasText = tk.StringVar()
        self.biasEntry = tk.Entry(self.firstFrame, width = 50, textvariable = self.biasText)
        self.browsebias = tk.Button(self.firstFrame, text = "Browse", command = self.uploadBias)
        
        self.enterButton = tk.Button(self.firstFrame, text = "Create Masters", command = self.mastercalibrations)
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        # Placement
        
        self.firstFrame.pack()
        self.secondFrame.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.thirdFrame.pack(side = 'right', padx = 5, pady = 5)
        
        #First Frame
        
        self.initialY = 5
        self.spacing = 30
        
        self.description.place(x = 5, y = 5)
        self.flatsLabel.place(x = 5, y = self.initialY + self.spacing)
        self.flatsEntry.place(x = 200, y = self.initialY + self.spacing)
        self.browseflats.place(x = 510, y = self.initialY + self.spacing)
        self.darksLabel.place(x = 5, y = self.initialY + 2 * self.spacing)
        self.darksEntry.place(x = 200, y = self.initialY + 2 * self.spacing)
        self.browsedarks.place(x = 510, y = self.initialY + 2 * self.spacing)
        self.biasLabel.place(x = 5, y = self.initialY + 3 * self.spacing)
        self.biasEntry.place(x = 200, y = self.initialY + 3 * self.spacing)
        self.browsebias.place(x = 510, y = self.initialY + 3 * self.spacing)
        self.enterButton.place(x = 5, y = self.initialY + 4 * self.spacing)
        
        
        self.mainWin.mainloop()
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def uploadFlats(self, entry):
        self.directory = dlg.askdirectory()
        
        #Delete current text in image name entry and replace with found image name
        entry.set(0, self.directory)
    
    def uploadDarks(self):
        self.directory = dlg.askdirectory()
        
        #Delete current text in image name entry and replace with found image name
        self.darksEntry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.darksEntry.insert(0, self.directory)
    
    def uploadBias(self):
        self.directory = dlg.askdirectory()
        
        #Delete current text in image name entry and replace with found image name
        self.biasEntry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.biasEntry.insert(0, self.directory)
        
        
    def mastercalibrations(self):
        print('m')
```

I have tried using lambda functions, the partial function, and have tried seeing if it is just an issue with the my function itself. Regardless of what the uploadFlats actually does, I'm given this same error. I have tried sending in multiple different types of variables, however they are all consistently ignored.

Comment: The Button that you used a `lambda` with, namely `self.browseflats`, probably *would* have worked - if you hadn't overwritten it with another definition of `self.browseflats` that didn't use `lambda`.

Comment: I feel so dumb because I realize I made that extra one for a save directory and hadn't renamed it.... Thank you very much!